# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PhotoService (?)

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm starting with Nest.js and I'm getting an error after I create a service:

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PhotoService (?). Please verify whether [0] argument is available in the current context.

I'm following the database example: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database

Here is my full code:
https://github.com/marceloHashzen/nestjsbasics

Comment: If you are using Nestjs 5 then check out this issue:  https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/723.  Add your name if it applies.

Comment: Hello Preston, I'm not sure if my problem is the same. I started a new project already with Nest 5, and Vladyslav's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In your `app.module.ts` remove `PhotoService` from providers.
Then in `PhotoModule`, just export `PhotoService`:

```
@Module({
  // ...prev code
  exports: [PhotoService],
})
```

Comment: Hello @Vladyslav, this solved my problem! But I'm a little confused of why, the PhotoService was added by the `nest g service` command, I need to always create the services manually and then export them at their own module?

Comment: I had the similar issue you had and I asked a question, this is the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50822301/nestjs-cannot-resolve-dependencies-of-the-usersmodule . I think it's the best explanation.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot!

Comment: This is not working. I've fetched repository from Marcelo, changed the things and nothing... there has to be another solution

Comment: Thank you, @VladyslavMoisieienkov. Your answer helped me a lot!

Comment: it fixed my problem, but now im mad because I've just followed the docs '-'

Answer (score 7):

Please remove any `providers` and `controllers` from `app.module.ts`.
Even if they were added by the CLI tool.

In `app.module.ts` you are only supposed to load other modules in the `imports`

```
imports: [
  WaterModule,
  FireModule,
  AirModule,
  EarthModule,
]
```

Is up to each specific module to explicit define what `imports`, `providers` and `exports` can be used.

in: `fire.module.ts`

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([FireRepository])],
  controllers: [FireController],
  providers: [FireService],
  exports: [FireService],
})
export class FireModule {}
```

Answer (score 5):

What helped me was in test use mock of PhotoService. Documentation was helpful https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers

Or have a look on the test spec I've wrote.

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { PhotoController } from './photo.controller';
import { PhotoService } from './photo.service';

describe('PhotoController', () => {
  let module: TestingModule;
  let photoController: PhotoController;
  let photoService: PhotoService;

  const resultAll = ['test'];

  const mockPhotoService = {
    findAll: () => (resultAll),
  };

  const photoServiceProvider = {
    provide: PhotoService,
    useValue: mockPhotoService,
  };

  beforeAll(async () => {
    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [PhotoController],
      providers: [photoServiceProvider],
    }).compile();

    photoService = module.get<PhotoService>(PhotoService);
    photoController = module.get<PhotoController>(PhotoController);
  });

  describe('findAll', () => {
    it('should return collection of photos', async () => {
      jest.spyOn(photoService, 'findAll').mockImplementation(() => resultAll);

      expect(await photoController.findAll()).toBe(resultAll);
    });
  });
});
```

Let me know if it helped you as well

Answer (score 4):

#### Pay attention to the order you are importing your services

If you import your services like this in `shared.module.ts`

```
// shared.module.ts

MyServiceOne
MyServiceTwo
```

make sure that you also declare them in the same order in the `constructor`.

```
// my-service-one.service.ts

export class MyServiceOne {
  constructor(@InjectModel(MyOne.name) private myOneModel: Model<MyOneModelDocument>,
    private myServiceTwo: MyServiceTwo) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hit the same problem when making an application **without sub-modules** (just an application module).

My workaround was to obtain the repository from the connection.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Repository, Connection } from 'typeorm';
import { AuthorEntity } from '../entities/AuthorEntity';

@Injectable()
export class AuthorsService {
    usersRepository: Repository<AuthorEntity>;

    constructor(private connection: Connection) {
        this.usersRepository = connection.getRepository(AuthorEntity);
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using mongoose for the models. For me, this was due to missing `imports` for the model I declared:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'ModelName', schema: ModelNameSchema }])], // <-- THIS WAS MISSING
  providers: [ModelNameService],
  controllers: [ModelNameController]
})
export class ModelNameModule {}
```