# NestJS Cannot resolve dependencies of the UsersModule

Tags: typescript, nestjs

NestJS Cannot resolve dependencies of the UsersModule. Error:

> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersModule (?). Please
> verify whether [0] argument is available in the current context.

app.module.ts:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    DatabaseModule,
    GraphQLModule,
    UsersModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ErrorService,
  ],
  exports: [
    DatabaseModule,
    ErrorService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {}
```

users.module.ts:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        DatabaseModule,
        ErrorService,
    ],
    providers: [
        UsersService,
        ...usersProviders,
        UserResolver,
    ],
})
export class UsersModule {
    constructor(private readonly errorService: ErrorService) {}
}
```

Problem is this ErrorService, but for instance Database module is used in similar way, and it works without any error. I'm little confused) Maybe somebody would help. Thank you.

Comment: Vlad, I'm getting this message with booting up Nestjs 5 and filed a Github issue for it.  So have others with v5.  We may be chasing our tails trying to solve this.  I think I just saw another post recently, like hours ago, with this same message.

Comment: Could share a link to the Github issue, please? @Preston

Comment: Oops, sorry.  https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/723

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`ErrorService` is not properly injected in `UsersModule`.

It should either be:

- In the `providers` of `UsersModule`
- In the `exports` of one module `import`ed by `UsersModule`

Otherwise, Nest won't be able to resolve it. And adding it to the `exports` of `AppModule` doesn't make it globally available, either.

I can see three solutions:

- 1 - Adding `ErrorService` to the `providers` of `UsersModule`. But it doesn't look a proper way, as I think/guess that you will reuse this service in many other parts of the code (right?). Thus, better:
- 2 - Create a `ErrorsModule` which `exports` the `ErrorService`, then `UsersModule` will `import` `ErrorsModule` and will be able to inject the service.

Like:

```
// errors.module.ts
@Module({
  providers: [ ErrorService ],
  exports: [ ErrorService ],
})
export class ErrorsModule {}

// users.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [ErrorsModule],
})
export class UsersModule {
  constructor(private readonly errorService: ErrorService) {}
}
```

- 3 - If your service is supposed to be reused (would `LoggerService` be a better name? If my guess is correct), you could use a `@Global` module that you'll `import` only once in your main module (`AppModule`)

Example:

```
@Global()
@Module({
  providers: [LoggerService],
  exports: [LoggerService],
})
export class LoggerModule {
  constructor(private readonly loggerService: LoggerService) { /* initialize logger, or whatever */ }
}
```

Then you **must** add `LoggerModule` to the `imports` of `AppModule`, and `LoggerService` will be injectable anywhere without having to re-declare it.

Comment: I was thinking about adding Errors Module, but I thought that is possible to inject service in this way. Your solution with the module is great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a wrong used of the Inject function:

I had this:

```
export class UsersModule {
    constructor(
         @Inject()
         private readonly errorService: ErrorService
     ) {}

}
```

Instead of this:

```
export class UsersModule {
    constructor(private readonly errorService: ErrorService) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for you to import the error service because it is already imported in the users module your code should be like this: 
app.module.ts

```
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    DatabaseModule,
    GraphQLModule,
    UsersModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ErrorService,
  ],
  exports: [
    DatabaseModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {}
```

user.module.ts

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        DatabaseModule,
        ErrorService,
    ],
    providers: [
        UsersService,
        ...usersProviders,
        UserResolver,
    ],
})
export class UsersModule {
    constructor(private readonly errorService: ErrorService) {}
}
```