# Unclear error message "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the XXXController (?) <...>" in NestJS

Tags: nestjs

The part after `(?)` of error message is unclear:

> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MemberController (?).
> Please make sure that the argument Object at index [0] is available in
> the MemberModule context.
>
> Potential solutions:
>
> - If Object is a provider, is it part of the current MemberModule?
> - If Object is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within MemberModule?   @Module({
>   imports: [ /* the Module containing Object */ ]   })

Here the incomprehensible moments are:

1. `Object` is a broad concept; I can't understand on what it refers
2. `Object at index [0]` - at index of what?
3. `MemberModule context` - again, the `context` is a broad concept. Is `context` the property of some object?
4. `If Object is a provider, is it part of the current MemberModule?` - what means the difference between "part of" and "not part of"?

#### Main module

```js
@NestJS_Module({
  imports: [
    MemberModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: "postgres",
      host: "localhost",
      port: 5432,
      username: "*******",
      password: "*******",
      database: "*******",
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: __IS_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__
    })
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: []
})
export default class NestJS_Application {}
```

#### Member module

```js
import { Module as NestJS_Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import MemberModel from "../Data/FromDataBase/Models/Member.model";
import MemberController from "../Controllers/Member.controller";
import MemberTypeORM_Gateway from "../Data/FromDataBase/Gateways/MemberTypeORM_Gateway";


@NestJS_Module({
  imports: [ TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ MemberModel ]) ],
  controllers: [ MemberController ],
  providers: [ MemberTypeORM_Gateway ]
})
export default class MemberModule {}
```

#### Member controller

```js
@Controller()
export default class MemberController {

  private readonly memberService: MemberGateway;

  public constructor(applicationService: MemberGateway) {
    this.memberService = applicationService;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Because I tried tried the solution for [Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PhotoService (?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50808189/nest-cant-resolve-dependencies-of-the-photoservice), here must the other solution.

Comment: `Object at index [0]` of `MemberController`, thus `MemberGateway`. This means that Nest can't find that dependecy. From where `MemberGateway` came? btw [read the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors#cannot-resolve-dependency-error)

Comment: @MicaelLevi, Thank you for the answer. `MemberGateway` is the framework independent interface, and `MemberTypeORM_Gateway` is it's NestJS + TypeORM implementation.

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#di-fundamentals you can't use interfaces like concrete classes and expect they behave in the same way. You'll have to use `@Inject('token') applicationService: MemberGateway`

Comment: @MicaelLevi, Solved! Thank you for the comment answer.